# Simulate mouse / keyboard in vmware

Tags: keyboard, mouse, vmware, simulate

I have a couple of Windows 7 running in vmware workstation and i want to make an application that make some mouseclicks / keypress while running a game.
I made a c# program that uses some dllimport for simulate:

```
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
```

This works good on a normal pc but when i run it in vmware and i open the game it doesnt click anymore.

how can i fix this :D

Stefan.

Comment: Are your game and the application are running both in in the vm?

Comment: yes, im running windows 7 and install vmware, in vmware i got 3 virtual machines with windows 7 running the game and the application.